Camel onexception retry failure route
I am new to camel and on exception I am calling a failureRoute and in failureRoute I am writing failed messaged to MQ. But In case of any exception in failure route like connecting to MQ I want to retry failureRoute atleast 3 times.
onException(Exception.class)
    .useOriginalMessage()
    .handled(true)
    .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "Exception --> ${exception.stacktrace}")
    .to("direct:failureRoute");

from("direct:failureRoute")
    .transacted()
    .routeId("failure-route")
    .to("wmqJmsTemplate:{{mq.failure.queue}}?preserveMessageQos=true")


You should create a redelivery policy, with number of retries set to 3.
protected RedeliveryPolicyDefinition createRedeliveryPolicy(String maximumRedeliveries,
                                                            String redeliveryDelay) {
    RedeliveryPolicyDefinition redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicyDefinition();
    redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(maximumRedeliveries);
    redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(redeliveryDelay);
    redeliveryPolicy.retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN);
    redeliveryPolicy.logRetryStackTrace(false);
    return redeliveryPolicy;
}

Where the parameter maximumRedeliveries is set to 3.
An example would be :
from("direct:failureRoute")
.transacted()
.routeId("failure-route")
.to("wmqJmsTemplate:{{mq.failure.queue}}?preserveMessageQos=true")
.onException(Exception.class)
    .useOriginalMessage()
    .handled(true)
    .process(this::logException)
    .onRedelivery(this::logAttemptRedelivery)
    .maximumRedeliveries(3)
    .redeliveryDelay(1000)
    .process(exchange -> {
        // Accessing and logging the original message
        Message originalMessage = exchange.getIn();
        String originalBody = originalMessage.getBody(String.class);
        LoggerFactory.getLogger("RedeliveryLogger").error("Final retry failed. Original Message: " + originalBody);
    })
    .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "Failed after max retry attempts. Original Message: ${body}")
    .to("log:failedMessages?level=ERROR")
    .end()
.to("direct:failureRoute");

And to configure logback :

Thanks. After retires how to write original message to log file ?

@VKR You have to configure logback for proper logging, if you want to log you can use just a processor after to log.
Any i updated my answer.

@VKR if my answer helped you solve the problem, please mark it as an answer.
